# How to read JavaScript & CSS files present in WEB-INF folder with Anonymous access in XPages

Tags: xpages

I have created a theme which has few referenced plugins and CSS (jQuery, bootstrap etc). These files are present in WEB-INF folder. I'm creating a XPage by using these files and want to make this page available to anonymous users. I have tried "Allow Public Access" to specific XPage but that doesn't solve my problem because CSS doesn't apply to the page. How can I solve this issue.

Comment: Public access is maintained per file (per design element). This will be extremely tedious to implement and maintain. You would be better off just adding the framework to the server itself, rather than trying to bundle it inside the app.

Answer (score 5):

Add the files as Resources - Files design elements. You can control public access for these design elements.

You can also use the CSS and Script Libraries design elements for this.

**Update:** You can mimic a directory structure in Files by using "/". For instance, using "css/main.css" as the file name for a CSS file makes it possible to reference it as being in a directory called css. So the following stylesheet reference in XPages will work:

```
<xp:styleSheet href="/css/main.css"></xp:styleSheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

WEB-INF is not exposed to the outside. WebContent  (the parent folder) is. Unless your whole app provides Anonymous access follow Per's suggestion and use the Design elements. 
If you need a file structure in those, use webdav access when copying - or add the Navigator view and use import

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for suggestions @Tim, @Per Henrik & @ stwissel. For now i have moved all my files to other database where i have anonymous reader access. Upon successful login i'm redirecting it to my current db.